# Can I replace Qt4 editor QTextEdit with vim?

Tags: vim, qt4, editor

I am making GUI, primarily for myself. And the problem is that the mainstream text editor is QTextEdit, and I am most comfortable with vim as an editor.

This place I am talking about has to be in GUI and I can't just make it a text file.

Is there a way I can employ 'vim', or any other standalone editor, inside Qt4 GUI as a plug in replacement of QTextEdit? Maybe some library that can work as a convertor between QWidget and standalone unix-style editor?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, Vim is not available as a library. But you can get inspiration from [this QT port of GVim](https://bitbucket.org/equalsraf/vim-qt/wiki/Home).